# Error Logging versus Showing Error to User

Tags: apex, visualforce, bestpractice

What is a better strategy when writing apex or visualforce code, with respect to error logging?

- Show errors occurred to end user (OR)
- silently log them to a custom object (OR)
- both of the above

Comment: If the error affects what the user is trying to do, show it to them. If an error is one of the expected outcomes (rare but there are a few use cases) then just log it. You really should be surfacing most error to the user when they occur. Login is only useful for debugging if you can replicate the error, otherwise login is useless since you have to be catching they blog as they occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't matter the language/platform, the best practises around showing errors & logging are the same, it's only the implementation that differs.

- If you have an error that impacts user functionality, then it's expected to show an error to user, but verbosity is a factor.

  1. If you're having errors that is part of normal application flow (e.g. validation errors), then you can provide pretty much direct errors to the user of what is wrong (bar any sensitive information like passwords);
  2. If you have exception in the code, that is stopping user data from being saved, then you wouldn't want to show the stack trace to the user, but you would want to inform the user that the data was not saved.
- If you have an exception within an app, you would like to log as much information as possible about it to be able to solve the issue, but you don't want to be logging errors that are part of normal application flow.

  1. If it's exception, log exception with stacktrace, application state, etc. that will help you reproduce the exception and fix the issue.
  2. If it's normal application flow (e.g. validation), do not log.

Comment: Nice! +1. Welcome to SFSE.